# pdcurses, лишние символы во время вывода

Tags: c++, ncurses, curses

Добрый день. 
Использую библиотеку pdcurses(curses для win) для простенькой игры. 
Во время вывода различными функциями, например mvwprintw(); возникают непонятно откуда, дополнительные символы.

Пример:

```
char s186 = 186;
mvwprintw(screen, i, 0, &s186);
```

Получаем: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему это происходит.

Comment: Происходит, судя по всему, неправильное использование функции. Беглое гугление приводит меня к мысли, что надо писать mvwprintw(screen, i, 0, "%c", s186); если вам нужно вывести символ с кодом из s186.

Answer (score 1):

`man mvwprintw` показывает это:

```
...
int mvwprintw(WINDOW *win, int y, int x, const char *fmt, ...); 
...
```

По прототипу понятно, что эта функция - из семейства [printf()](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#.D0.A1.D0.B8.D0.BD.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BA.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.81_.D1.81.D1.82.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D1.84.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F), поэтому использовать для вывода символа нужно так:

```
mvwprintw(win, y, x, "%c", c);
```

Comment: Благодарю, получилось. 
Я не правильно читал документацию.